# Hover on svg in cypress and test tooltip

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

Scenario:

I have something similar:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Using g to inherit presentation attributes -->
  <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Hovering over svg will show a tooltip and I need to test whether tooltip is displayed and the content is correct.

Any suggestions? Tried `trigger(mouseover)` which in not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, using 'mousemove' instead of 'mouseover' worked for me.

```
cy.get('g circle').each((circ) => {
  cy.get(circ).trigger('mousemove', { force: true })
    .wait(100)
    .get('table tbody tr td').each((data) => {
      cy.log(data.text())
    })
})
```